# Wordpress child theme images are coming up blank

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Ok for some reason all images are not linking to the right directory after the latest update.

normal child theme setup;

normal html and php to customise theme.

foot.php

```html
<div id="left_arrow"><img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/left_arrow.png" alt="image" width="372" height="551" /></div>
```

I have no idea why this is not working any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't it be  `src="<?=get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/left_arrow.png"`  ?

Comment: This method also doesn't work... but thanks Alex.

Comment: is this image is inside theme directory or any other folder?

Comment: Do not sign your post, SO does this automatiicaly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open PHP back up in your code. The above comment was missing the closing ; on PHP. The one below worked on PHPfiddle.

```
<div id="left_arrow"><img src="<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/left_arrow.png" alt="image" width="372" height="551" /></div>
```